# How can i transport specific columns in a row?(on Edit function)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have this code where it uses a checkbox confirmation to transport and entire row to another sheet. The thing is, i don't want to transport the entire row, only some columns of data.
This columns would be column A to E and column J. Is there a way to improve the code to do that function? (Code below)

```
    function onEdit(event) { // COD ATUALIZADO 22/11/22

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Ativa planilha
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet(); // Página origem do evento
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange(); // Página fim do evento
  var row = r.getRow();

  if(s.getName() == "DEMANDAS" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true && s.getRange(row,5).getValue() == "CORRETIVA") {
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn(); // Número de colunas
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("EQUIPAMENTOS PARA CORRETIVA"); // Planilha alvo
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); // Local alvo
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target); // Insere no local alvo
    s.deleteRow(row); // Exclui a origem
    target.offset(0, numColumns).setValue(new Date()); // Inclui a data pós checkbox
  }
  if(s.getName() == "DEMANDAS" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) { // Se condições OK(IDA)
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn(); // Número de colunas
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LIBERADOS"); // Planilha alvo
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); // Local alvo
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target); // Insere no local alvo
    s.deleteRow(row); // Exclui a origem
    target.offset(0, numColumns).setValue(new Date()); // Inclui a data pós checkbox

  } else if(s.getName() == "LIBERADOS" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == false) { // Se condições OK(VOLTA)
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn(); // Número de colunas
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DEMANDAS"); // Planilha alvo
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); // Local alvo
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target); // Insere no local alvo
    s.deleteRow(row); // Exclui a origem
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the values of columns "A" to "E" and "J" instead of all columns by modifying your showing script.

When I saw your script, I thought that your script might be able to become simpler a little. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = event.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.range;
  var row = r.rowStart;
  var sheetName = s.getSheetName();
  var value = r.getValue();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet;
  if (sheetName == "DEMANDAS" && r.columnStart == 1 && value === true) {
    targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(r.offset(0, 4).getValue() == "CORRETIVA" ? "EQUIPAMENTOS PARA CORRETIVA" : "LIBERADOS");
  } else if (sheetName == "LIBERADOS" && r.columnStart == 1 && value === false) {
    targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DEMANDAS");
  }
  if (!targetSheet) return;
  var [a, b, c, d, e, , , , , j] = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()[0];
  targetSheet.appendRow([a, b, c, d, e, j, new Date()]);
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 1).insertCheckboxes();
  s.deleteRow(row);
}
```

- In this modification, the values of columns "A" to "E" and "J" and `new Date()` are appended to the sheet you want. In your showing script, `new Date()` is put to `target.offset(0, numColumns).setValue(new Date())`. But, from your expected situation, I guessed that you might want to put `new Date()` in the last column of the appended value. So, I used `targetSheet.appendRow([a, b, c, d, e, j, new Date()]);`.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to do it.

Here it goes

```
    function onEdit(event) { // COD ATUALIZADO 22/11/22

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Ativa planilha
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet(); // Página origem do evento
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange(); // Página fim do evento
  var row = r.getRow();


  if(s.getName() == "DEMANDAS" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true && s.getRange(row,5).getValue() == "CORRETIVA") {
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn(); // Número de colunas
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("EQUIPAMENTOS PARA CORRETIVA"); // Planilha alvo
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); // Local alvo
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target); // Insere no local alvo
    
    s.deleteRow(row); // Exclui a origem
    target.offset(0, numColumns).setValue(new Date()); // Inclui a data pós checkbox
  }
  if(s.getName() == "DEMANDAS" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) { // Se condições OK(IDA)
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn(); // Número de colunas
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("LIBERADOS"); // Planilha alvo
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    var target2 = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 11); // Local alvo
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 5).moveTo(target);
    s.getRange(row, 10, 1, 1).moveTo(target2); // Insere no local alvo
    s.deleteRow(row); // Exclui a origem
    target.offset(0, numColumns).setValue(new Date()); // Inclui a data pós checkbox
    }
}
```